# Flutter: Retrieve associated object from Future in FutureBuilder widget

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I am fetching the user 'event manager id' data coming from a future of the object 'event'. I would like now to fetch a user using that id to display his name next the event. However, my FutureBuilder widget only takes into account one future (Event) and I am not able to retrieve that user's name based on that event since my fetchUser method will only return Future objects.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the FutureBuilder widget:

```
        body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: events,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
          List<Event> availableEvents = snapshot.data;
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          return new ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            itemCount: availableEvents.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              user = fetchUserbyId( // Here, user is of type Future<user> and I cannot retrieve info such as the name of that user
                  (availableEvents[index].managerId).toString());
              return new Container(
                  margin: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 6.0),
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text('${availableEvents[index].name}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              height: _height,
                              fontSize: 18)),
                      new Text('${availableEvents[index].description}',
                          style: TextStyle(height: _height)),
                      new Text('${availableEvents[index].address}',
                          style: TextStyle(height: _height)),
                      new Text('${availableEvents[index].datetime}',
                          style: TextStyle(height: _height)),
                      //new Text('${availableEvents[index].managerId}', style: TextStyle(height: _height)),

                      new FlatButton(
                        onPressed: null,
                        // Simply call joinEvent for event 'availableEvents[index]'
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        disabledColor: Colors.red,
                        disabledTextColor: Colors.white,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
                        child: Text('Join!'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ));
            },
          );
        }));
```

Here is the fetchUserByID method:

```
    Future<User> fetchUserbyId(String id) async {
  final response =
      await http.get('https://url-here.com' + id);
  //print("response : " + response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON.
    return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what I'm understanding is you have two asynchronous calls, where the second one needs the results of the first call to execute. The best way to go around this is to create a helper method, i.e. `getData()`. In this method you make your call to `events` and then use that to `fetchUserbyId`. This would result in your FutureBuilder looking something like this:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: getData()
  builder: ... // get the results the same why you got your results from events in the given example.
);
```

Then in you `getData()` method it would look something like this:

```dart
Future<User> getData() async {
  var availableEvents= await events; // not sure what your events data/method is
  return fetchUserbyId((availableEvents[index].managerId).toString());
}
```

I think I answered your question, but if I missed it please comment.

---

Note: On a completely unrelated topic, you don't need the `new` keyword in Flutter anymore to instantiate objects. Hope that speeds up your development process!

Comment: Thanks for replying but that appears to not be working for me. I cannot use a helper method in the way you suggested it as my availableEvents are already fetched from a previous fetchEvents method (hence why I am using snapshot.data to define that variable).

Comment: Are you fetching the results outside of the FutureBuilder and are they used outside the FutureBuilder. I'm confused on what your `events` is when you use it as the future in your FutureBuilder.

Comment: My event list is fetched outside of the FutureBuilder and stored as the list variable  **Future<List<Event>> events**. But they are not used other than inside of the FutureBuilder where I set the future as **events**.

Comment: So essentially you need to convert the `Future<List<Event>>` to `List<Event>`. I'm not sure on the code behind that if this didn't work though: `var availableEvents= await events;`

Comment: @symbolads Ways I would get around this is to somehow store the variable as a `List<Event>` by using `await` wherever you fetch the events, or if you are only using the events inside your `FutureBuilder` just fetch the data inside the `getData` method. Reply if none of these methods work. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @symbolads , did any of these suggestions work for you?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! (Had to stop working on that for a while). Anyway, having a getData method which returned a future of the user model and use the ''then'' keyword fixed it for me. However, I still decided to go with another implementation which is less cumbersome and results in a cleaner user interface. Thank you again for helping :)

Comment: Glad I could help, if it helped you please up vote, good luck in the future!